# Identifying existing water softener connections

Tags: plumbing, water-softener

My friend is installing a water softener in the house where the softener of unknown brand was previously installed. The existing connection consists of some sort of clip coupling with double o-rings, that I've never seen. It's 1" (~25 mm) outside diameter, and ¾" (~19 mm) inside diameter.

[image: photograph of the water softener connection]

I went to a reputable plumbing supply, but they've told me that those are proprietary, and that they wouldn't be carrying it. I don't even know what these are called, but I need adapter to a regular ¾" MPT for the flex hose to the new tank.

Answer (score 1):

I agree: this connector is probably proprietary. You'll need to remove it. I suggest removing both the yellow brass part and the copper elbow together by desoldering the elbow-to-pipe joint. Clean it up, add more flux, and solder male adapter fittings to the ends of the pipes.

As an alternative to soldering, the 3/4" pipe could be cut and cleaned so that push-on fittings may be used (commonly called "Shark bite" after the genericized brand name).

Answer (score 1):

I have similar items and they were used to allow quick connect and disconnect of the softener tank. The tanks were exchanged on a regular basis and taken back to be recharged at the softener suppliers facility, eliminating the customer for normal maintenance, purchasing salt, etc. Check with the previous owner or the neighbors as to who that company is, it may be a better deal if you keep the exchange system. You will have to do the costing to determine that. Your picture did not show but I would guess there is a valve between the pipes connecting the two fittings which is open if your water system is operating.